# Is it possible to store data within 2 for-loops

Tags: arrays, c, string, for-loop

I want to ask a user to give me a series of questions within 2 or 3 separate categories. I then want to print out these same questions within the 2 or 3 separate categories. I am using a for-loop within a for-loop, but when I print, the system only prints out questions from the latest for-loop. Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    int tiers;
    char *question [81]; // pointers to binary questions
    int num[81];  // number of binary questions to be asked

    printf("How many tiers do you have? For example if you have high, medium and low categories, you 
    have three tiers.\n");
    scanf("%i", &tiers);

    for (int i = 0; i < tiers; ++i)
    {
        printf("You are in tier number %i\n\n", i+1);
        printf("You will be asked to write a series of binary questions.\n");
        printf("How many questions are you going to ask?\n");
        scanf("%i", &num[i]);
        getchar();

        for (int j =0; j<num[i]; ++j)
        {
            question[j] = malloc(sizeof(char)*584);
            printf("What is question number %i\n", j+1);

            fgets(question[j], 584, stdin);
        }

        printf("\n\n\n");
    }


    /* From here the user is now a different person */
   //asking questions in the respective tiers

    for (int i = 0; i < tiers; ++i)
    {
            printf("You are in tier number %i\n", i+1);
            printf("I am now going to ask you a series of binary questions.\n");
            for ( int j =0; j <num[i]; ++j)
            {
                   printf("\n%s", question[j]);
            }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tiers; ++i)
    {
            for (int j =0; j<num[i]; ++j)
            {
                    free (question[j]);
            }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same array for all categories, so only input for last category are saved.

You have to use separate arrays to store all input.

In this code, `question` is 81 81-element arrays of `char*` instead of single 81-element array of `char*` in the original code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    int tiers;
    char *question [81][81]; // pointers to binary questions
    int num[81];  // number of binary questions to be asked

    printf("How many tiers do you have? For example if you have high, medium and low categories, you 
    have three tiers.\n");
    scanf("%i", &tiers);

    for (int i = 0; i < tiers; ++i)
    {
        printf("You are in tier number %i\n\n", i+1);
        printf("You will be asked to write a series of binary questions.\n");
        printf("How many questions are you going to ask?\n");
        scanf("%i", &num[i]);
        getchar();

        for (int j =0; j<num[i]; ++j)
        {
            question[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(char)*584);
            printf("What is question number %i\n", j+1);

            fgets(question[i][j], 584, stdin);
        }

        printf("\n\n\n");
    }


    /* From here the user is now a different person */
   //asking questions in the respective tiers

    for (int i = 0; i < tiers; ++i)
    {
            printf("You are in tier number %i\n", i+1);
            printf("I am now going to ask you a series of binary questions.\n");
            for ( int j =0; j <num[i]; ++j)
            {
                   printf("\n%s", question[i][j]);
            }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tiers; ++i)
    {
            for (int j =0; j<num[i]; ++j)
            {
                    free (question[i][j]);
            }
    }

    return 0;
}
```